# jQuery get HTML value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML code:

```
<p>Start Date: <span class="text-success" id="subscriptionStartDate">28/01/2015 4:49:43 a.m.</span></p>
```

How can I retrieve the value of `28/01/2015 4:49:43 a.m.` from the element with the id of `subscriptionStartDate`?

Here is what I have tried:

```
var startDate = $(".subscriptionStartDate").val();
```

This is however not getting any value at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `id selector` and use `.text()`,

```
var startDate = $("#subscriptionStartDate").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery  .text() or .html()

```
var startDate = $("#subscriptionStartDate").text();
```

or

```
var startDate = $("#subscriptionStartDate").html();
```

use "#" instead of '.' for id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : you can use `.text()` or `.html()`. You can use `.val()` for input elements having `value` attribute.

Also correct your jQuery selector to `id` selector using `#`

```
var startDate = $("#subscriptionStartDate").text();
```